# CKeditor not working in my second textarea editing,

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, ckeditor4.x

If I put my code in a single file to get a single webpage I get the results.
When introduce to the main page via get data with a function type with ajax it's not working, tried multiple solution but no winning one.
I've put the script tag with the url for ckeditor and still no luck.
But if I code it like just one page for a single website page, ckeditor works fine but not when link to another coded page in 2 separate files.
Need help and thanks

I've tried CKEDITOR.replaceAll(); in the script at the bottom of page before the end body tag like suggested and still only works for the first textarea.
I'll put the 2 files in question

items_list.php

```
 <?php

 include "../includes/db.php";

if(isset($_POST['item_submit'])){
    //mysqli_real_escape_string is a  web protection for intrusion
    $item_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_title']));
    $item_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_description']);
    $item_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_category']));
    $item_qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_qty']));
    $item_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_cost']));
    $item_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_price']));
    $item_discount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_discount']));
    $item_delivery = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_delivery']));

    if(isset($_FILES['item_image']['name'])){
        $file_name = $_FILES['item_image']['name'];         
        $path_address = "../images/items/$file_name";
        $path_address_db = "images/items/$file_name";
        $img_confirm = 1;
        $file_type = pathinfo($_FILES['item_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($_FILES['item_image']['size']>200000){
            $img_confirm = 0;
            echo "size 2 big";
        }
        if($file_type != 'jpg' && $file_type != 'png' && $file_type != 'gif'){
            $img_confirm = 0;
            echo "type mismatch";
        }
        if($img_confirm == 0){

        }else{
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['item_image']['tmp_name'], $path_address)){
                $item_ins_sql = "INSERT INTO items (item_image, item_title, item_description, item_cat, item_qty, item_cost, item_price, item_discount, item_delivery) VALUES ('$path_address_db','$item_title','$item_description','$item_category','$item_qty','$item_cost','$item_price','$item_discount','$item_delivery')";
                $item_ins_run = mysqli_query($conn, $item_ins_sql);
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo "sorry";
    }
}

if( isset($_POST['edit_submit'])){
    //include "item_list_process.php";
    $item_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_id']));
    $item_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_title1']));
    $item_description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['item_description1']);
    $item_category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_cat']));
    $item_qty = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_qty']));
    $item_cost = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_cost']));
    $item_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_price']));
    $item_discount = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_discount']));
    $item_delivery = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, strip_tags($_POST['item_delivery']));

    echo $item_id;
    $item_up_sql = "UPDATE items SET item_title = '$item_title', item_description = '$item_description', item_cat = '$item_category', item_qty = '$item_qty', item_cost = '$item_cost', item_price = '$item_price', item_discount = '$item_discount', item_delivery = '$item_delivery' WHERE item_id = '$item_id' ";
    $item_up_run = mysqli_query($conn, $item_up_sql);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Online Shopping | Admin Panel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin_style.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.1/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>

        function get_item_list_data(){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('get_item_list_data').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'item_list_process.php', true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

        function del_item(item_id){

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('get_item_list_data').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open('GET', 'item_list_process.php?del_item_id='+item_id, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }



    </script>

</head>
<body onload="get_item_list_data()">
    <?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="btn btn_red btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_new_item" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">Add New Item</button>
        <div id="add_new_item" class="modal fade">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add New Item</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addNewItemForm">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Image</label>
                                <input type="file" id="image" name="item_image" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter location on drive for the image of item" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Title</label>
                                <input type="text" id="item_title" name="item_title" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Title or Name of Item" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Description</label>
  <!------Here is the ckeditor that's working-------------->
                                <textarea class="form-control ckeditor" id="item_description" name="item_description" required></textarea>

                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Category</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="item_category" required>
                                    <option>Select a Category</option>
                                    <?php 
                                        $cat_sql = "SELECT * FROM item_cat";
                                        $cat_run = mysqli_query($conn, $cat_sql);
                                        while($cat_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_run)){
                                            $cat_name = ucwords($cat_rows['cat_name']);
                                            if($cat_rows['cat_slug'] == ''){
                                                $cat_slug = $cat_rows['cat_name'];
                                            }else{
                                                $cat_slug = $cat_rows['cat_slug'];
                                            }
                                            echo "
                                            <option value='$cat_slug'>$cat_name</option>";
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Quantity</label>
                                <input type="number" name="item_qty" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the quantity you have in stocks" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Cost</label>
                                <input type="number" name="item_cost" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the cost you paid for the item" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Price</label>
                                <input type="number" name="item_price" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the price to sell to clients" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Discount</label>
                                <input type="number" name="item_discount" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the amount of discount in dollars we are giving" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Item Delivery</label>
                                <input type="number" name="item_delivery" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the amount to charge for shipping">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="submit" name="item_submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="SUBMIT">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn_red btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="get_item_list_data">
        <!---------------------Area for process item list data------------>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php include "includes/footer.php";   ?>
    <script>
    //CKEDITOR.replaceAll();
    // CKEDITOR.instances.item_description.destroy();
    //CKEDITOR.replace( 'item_description' );

    //ckeditorOff();
    //CKEDITOR.add
    //CKEDITOR.replace( 'item_description1' );


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second file item_list_process.php

```
 <?php 
    include "../includes/db.php";
    if(isset($_REQUEST['del_item_id'])){

    $del_sql = "DELETE FROM items WHERE item_id = '$_REQUEST[del_item_id]'";
    $del_run = mysqli_query($conn, $del_sql);
    }
?>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="item-head">
                    <th>S. no.</th>
                    <th>Image</th>
                    <th>Item Title</th>
                    <th>Item Description</th>
                    <th>Item Category</th>
                    <th>Item Qty</th>
                    <th>Item Cost</th>
                    <th>Item Price</th>
                    <th>Item Discount</th>
                    <th>Item Delivery</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
                $c = 1;
                $sel_sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
                $sel_run = mysqli_query($conn, $sel_sql);
                while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sel_run)){
                    $discountPrice = $rows['item_price'] - $rows['item_discount'];
                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>$c</td>
                        <td><img src='../$rows[item_image]' style='width:30px'></td>
                        <td>$rows[item_title]</td>
                        <td>"; echo strip_tags($rows['item_description']); echo "</td>
                        <td>$rows[item_cat]</td>
                        <td>$rows[item_qty]</td>
                        <td>$rows[item_cost]</td>
                        <td>$rows[item_price]</td>
                        <td>$discountPrice($rows[item_discount])</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class='dropdown'>
                                <button class='btn  btn_red btn-danger dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>Actions<span class='caret'></span></button>
                                <ul class='dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right'>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='#edit_modal$rows[item_id]'  data-toggle='modal' >Edit</a>
                                    </li>";
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="del_item(<?php echo $rows['item_id'] ?>);">Delete</a></li>
                                <?php
                                echo "
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class='modal fade ' id='edit_modal$rows[item_id]' role='dialog'>
                                <div class='modal-dialog'>
                                    <div class='modal-content'>
                                        <div class='modal-header'>
                                            <button class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class='modal-title'>Edit Item</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class='modal-body'>
                                            <form method='post' name='editForm'>
                                            <input type='hidden' name='item_id' id='item_id' value='$rows[item_id]'>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Title</label>
                                                <input type='text' value='$rows[item_title]' id='item_title1' name='item_title1' class='form-control' required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group' id='tracking_text'>
                                                <label>Item Description</label>
 //-------------------This is for the second ckeditor--------------- >
                                                <textarea class='form-control ckeditor'  name='item_description1' id='item_description11' required>$rows[item_description]</textarea>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Category</label>
                                                <select class='form-control' value='$rows[item_cat]' name='item_cat' id='item_cat' required>
                                                    ";

                                                        $cat_sql = "SELECT * FROM item_cat";
                                                        $cat_run = mysqli_query($conn, $cat_sql);
                                                        while($cat_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cat_run)){
                                                            $cat_name = ucwords($cat_rows['cat_name']);
                                                            if($cat_rows['cat_slug'] == ''){
                                                                $cat_slug = $cat_rows['cat_name'];
                                                            }else{
                                                                $cat_slug = $cat_rows['cat_slug'];
                                                            }

                                                            if($cat_slug == $rows['item_cat']){
                                                                echo "
                                                            <option selected value='$cat_slug'>$cat_name</option>";
                                                            }else{
                                                                echo "
                                                            <option  value='$cat_slug'>$cat_name</option>";
                                                            }                                                               
                                                        }

                                                    echo "
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Quantity</label>
                                                <input type='number' value='$rows[item_qty]' name='item_qty' id='item_qty' class='form-control' required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Cost</label>
                                                <input type='number' value='$rows[item_cost]' name='item_cost' id='item_cost' class='form-control' required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Price</label>
                                                <input type='number' value='$rows[item_price]' name='item_price' id='item_price' class='form-control' required>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Discount</label>
                                                <input type='number' value='$rows[item_discount]' name='item_discount' id='item_discount' class='form-control'>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                <label>Item Delivery</label>
                                                <input type='number' value='$rows[item_delivery]' name='item_delivery' id='item_delivery' class='form-control'>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class='form-group'>
                                                ";

                                                ?>
                                                <button type="submit" name="edit_submit" id="edit_submit"  class='btn btn-primary btn-block' >SUBMIT</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                        </div> <!---end of modal body--->
                                        <div class='modal-footer'>
                                            <button class='btn btn_red btn-danger' data-dismiss='modal'>CLOSE</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!---end of modal content--->
                                </div> <!---end of modal dialog--->
                            </div> <!---end of modal div fade--->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $c++;
                    } 
                ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: could you show us how you do your code

Comment: i was editing the question, here is the  code above